# Making a request to a web service for logging purposes in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a web service with a URL like this: `http://webservice.com/?log=1`

I would like to make a request to this URL in Objective-C such that the web service can log that fact. I don't care to pass anything on to the web service and nor do I care how it responds to the request.

What is the most effective way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:) method.

e.g.

```
NSURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://webservice.com/?log=1"]] returningResponse: &response error: NULL];
```

The downside to using this method is that it will hang your app while it's performing the URL request. To do this request asynchronously you need to use the [connectionWithRequest:delegate:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/connectionWithRequest:delegate:) method.  This gets a little more complex as you need to provide a delegate (in your case, one that does nothing).

e.g.

```
    [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://webservice.com/?log=1"]] delegate:self] retain];

...

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [connection release];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [connection release];
}
```

See [SimpleURLConnections](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html) for more examples of using NSURLConnection.

UPDATE: removed optional delagate methods as per David's comment.

Comment: Excellent response Shane. Unfortunately it will need to be asynchronous so I'll just have to deal with a few empty delegate methods. That's fine by me. Thanks again.

Comment: Turns out NSURLConnection uses an informal protocol, and all methods are optional, so I only needed to include `connection:didFailWithError:` and `connectionDidFinishLoading:`.

Comment: I kind-of did know it was like that but I couldn't find any documentation on what was optional and what wasn't.   Maybe I didn't look hard enough!  I'll update my answer.  Thanks.